# 4-in-a-row on Fruit Ninja WP7?

Tags: fruit-ninja, windows-phone

Other than just playing the game constantly, and hoping the game will randomly dish out four of the same fruit in a row, is there any way to influence the game to give out four pears in a row?

I've got all achievements in the WP7 version of this game, with the exception of the two for getting four fruit in a row, and four pears in a row in classic mode. Do the different blades or backgrounds have any effect, or are they purely cosmetic? I'm up to over 15,000 fruit killed in this game, and I kinda thought I would've managed to get these achievements by now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the fruit which appears is random, there is no way to influence it.

Comment: Bummer. Well, looks like I got at least a little lucky today, as 3 pears appeared, and I was able to get that achievement off of my list.